# How can i track the status of the downstream pipeline when i use the trigger API?

Tags: triggers, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Currently i would like to trigger a pipeline that is part of another project. So one way could be to use multi-project pipelines via trigger keyword. The problem is that if i do it with this way then i have to be owner or maintainer in the downstream repo. This is not possible because the downstream repo has SSH_KEYS that must be hidden.

So the other way i followed is this:

1. Made desired branch protected in 'Downstream' repository
2. Created Pipeline triggers in 'Downstream' project : Settings -> CI/CD -> Pipeline triggers.
3. As an Admin - located this token as a Group CI/CD variable (or in the project which will trigger 'Downstream' project) - Group Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables.
4. Used it like below:

   ```
    curl -X POST \
    --form token=$YOU_TRIGGER_TOKEN_VARIABLE \
    --form ref=target_branch \
    "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/55/trigger/pipeline"
   ```

Is there any way to track the status of the triggered pipeline? Currently, there is no UI showing the triggered pipeline so how i should know if this was successful or not? There is also a strategy attribute (strategy:depend) when triggerring a child pipeline using trigger:project but it's not supported when using trigger API.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to know the downstream pipeline status, there is an internal feature request inside of gitlab, unfortunately, 3 years have gone they still don't move forward. We can vote to pop it up.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31566